# HttpClientFactory with Polly Timeout Policy doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, timeout, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I'm trying to implement a Polly Timeout policy using the new .NET Core 2.1 HttpClientFactory; however, I cannot seem to get the timeout to occur.

My `ConfigureServices`:

```cs
// Configure polly policies
TimeoutPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(5, TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic);

// Configure platform service clients
services.AddHttpClient<IDiscoveryClient, DiscoveryClient>()
    .AddPolicyHandler(timeoutPolicy);
```

My POST method in `DiscoveryClient`:

```cs
public async Task<TResponse> PostXMLAsync<TResponse, TPostData>(string url, TPostData postData)
    where TResponse : ClientResponse
    where TPostData : ClientPostData
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsXmlAsync(url, postData);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TResponse>();
}
```

Unfortunately, the call times out after the default 100s rather than after the 5s defined in the Polly policy.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you seeing the timeout? At `await httpClient.PostAsXmlAsync(url, postData)` or at `await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TResponse>()`? How are you seeing the timeout? In logs, or are you seeing a timeout thrown as an exception from either of  those two code lines?

Comment: Essentially, the 5s timeout is not happening. Instead, `await httpClient.PostAsXmlAsync(url, postData)` is taking 100s to complete and then I receive a `HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).` from `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` The service I'm calling is known to do this from time to time which is why I wanted to implement the Polly Timeout policy.

Comment: Can you confirm what happens with `TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic`? HttpClientFactory [definitely transmits the cancellationtoken downstream](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/926c85f25dccb6444be926743d0bb539f87799c3/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly/PolicyHttpMessageHandler.cs#L108-L130), so I would have expected `TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic` to be adequate.  Otherwise we will need to construct a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Comment: `TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic` doesn't seem to matter. I created a demo here: https://gist.github.com/wdspider/a1cf8328dbcf6cd42ea0a889f5427f0b
The slow responding web service that I'm calling is not public; therefore, I simply added a 20s delay in the `ClientLoggingHandler` which should be a decent simulation.

Comment: The timeout in https://gist.github.com/wdspider/a1cf8328dbcf6cd42ea0a889f5427f0b fails because the [order of delegating handlers](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-aspnetcore-outgoing-request-middleware-pipeline-delegatinghandlers) is such that the `await Task.Delay(...)` executes before (is 'outside', in terms of nesting) the `TimeoutPolicy`; ie the timeout policy doesn't govern the delay. Reverse it to `services....AddPolicyHandler(timeoutPolicy).AddHttpMessageHandler<ClientLoggingHandler>();` and the timeout works. Does this info help the original case?

Comment: That reordering does seem to work as I was originally expecting. I hadn't gleaned from the Polly docs that the policy order with the message handlers actually mattered; just that the policy order between policies mattered. Thanks for your help. If you want to rewrite your prev. comment as an answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: Thanks @wdspider. [Added to the Polly documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#combining-policyhttpmessagehandler-with-other-delegatinghandlers) to that effect.

Comment: I am seeing this issue with this piece of code:
`services.AddHttpClient(typeof(T).Name).AddPolicyHandler(GetPollyPolicies(retryCount, timeoutSeconds));` where as I combine this `waitAndRetryPolicy.WrapAsync(timeoutPerTryPolicy);` When I get the httpClient from CreateClient I look at the timeout it is set to default `100` seconds. @mountaintraveller

Answer (score 0):

First let's define a mock server which does respond with 500 after 100 seconds:

```cs
const string address = "http://localhost:9000";
var delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
var server = WireMockServer.Start(new WireMockServerSettings { Urls = new[] { address } });
server
    .Given(Request.Create().WithPath("/").UsingPost())
    .RespondWith(Response.Create().WithDelay(delay).WithStatusCode(500));
```

I've used [WireMock.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WireMock.Net/) for this.

Now, let's see the `IDiscoveryClient` and `DiscoveryClient`:

```cs
interface IDiscoveryClient
{
    Task<TResponse> SendRequest<TResponse, TPostData>(string url, TPostData data);
}
```

```cs
class DiscoveryClient : IDiscoveryClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public DiscoveryClient(HttpClient httpClient) => this.httpClient = httpClient;

    public async Task<TResponse> SendRequest<TResponse, TPostData>(string url, TPostData data)
    {
        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), Encoding.UTF8);
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var rawData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(rawData);
    }
}
```

```cs
class TestRequest { public string Content { get; set; } }
class TestResponse { public string Data { get; set; } }
```

I've used json instead of xml, but that's not imporant from the question point of view.

And finally let's wire up the DI and issue a request:

```cs
AsyncTimeoutPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> timeoutPolicy =
    Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(5, TimeoutStrategy.Pessimistic);

IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddHttpClient<IDiscoveryClient, DiscoveryClient>()
    .AddPolicyHandler(timeoutPolicy);

ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var client = serviceProvider.GetService<IDiscoveryClient>();

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
try
{
    TestResponse res = await client.SendRequest<TestResponse, TestRequest>(address, new TestRequest { Content =  "Test"});
}
catch (TimeoutRejectedException ex)
{
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
}
```

The printed output will be something like this:

```
00:00:05.0296804
```

The good thing is that it does work with `Optimistic` and `Pessimistic` strategies as well.